# Picard numbers of ordinary varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth proper variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ with good ordinary reduction $X_0$ at a prime $p$.

Can $X_0$ and $X$ have different (geometric) picard numbers?

Comment: Probably yes. Let $X$ be a K3 surface over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has geometric Picard rank one. Then, for any prime $p$ such that $X$ has good reduction, the resulting K3 surface has even Picard rank, hence Picard rank at least two. I do not know how to show that there is a prime $p$ such that $X_p$ is ordinary (and smooth), but I would expect such a prime $p$ always exists.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Does the difficulty remain if we allow finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$? It is apparently known that after making such an extension, $X$ has good ordinary reduction at almost all places. So it would be enough to find a K3 defined over some number field that has odd Picard rank.